# Cannot queryselect a shadowRoot on button click(for toggling view)

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

I have a parent component `ha-config-user-picker.js` and child component `edit-user-view.js`.

**Parent component:**
has a mapping of users and also has the child component tag with its props.
the click event gets the shadowRoot of the child component and invokes method `toggleView`.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]" as="user">
    <paper-button on-click="clickEditUser">
      <paper-item>
        ...
      </paper-item>
    </paper-button>
  </template>

  <edit-user-view hass="[[hass]]" user="[[user]]"></edit-user-view>

  clickEditUser(ev) {
    this.user = ev.model.user;
    const el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("edit-user-view");
    el.toggleView();
  }
```

**Child Component:**

```
<fullscreen-pop-up>
   <dialog-header title="Edit User"></dialog-header>
   <div class="content">
     ...
   </div>
</fullscreen-pop-up>

toggleView = () => {
    const popup = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("fullscreen-pop-up");
    const dialog = popup.shadowRoot.querySelector("paper-dialog");
    dialog.toggle();
}
```

**Error:**
So when I click on a mapped user. First I get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null`. which is `const popup = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("fullscreen-pop-up");`. So the popup returns null.

But if i click any user again. it gets the shadowRoot and works fine.

**Question:** So why is it null the first time and works after that?
and how do I solve this?
Can this might be the problem?
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/5144

Let me know if you need something more to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `toggleView` method is not executed in the context of your child component, you can try to `console.log(this)` before using `this` and you will see it's not the element.

You can try something like replacing:

```
el.toggleView();
```

with

```
el.toggleView.call(el);
```

to see if this is the issue and if so refactor your code however you see fit. Please note that I did not test this at this moment, so there might be small differences.